# How to check in from multiple views in Clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have a file which is checked out in 5 different dynamic views, all pointing to the latest version of the same development branch. Now this is obviously a beginner's question but how can I merge/check in the modifications from all views without introducing a "predecessor is not latest" problem? If I check the file in from *view 1* where it is reserved, this will create a new version on the dev branch and make it impossible for me to check the file in from the other views afterward.

Comment: "make it impossible for me to check the file in from the other views afterward.": it will still be possible, but the checkin will merge your checked out version. If you are using a snapshot view, update it first (as seen in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21133455)

Comment: The page mentions snapshot views and a certain patch that might be needed. The views I'm dealing with are dynamic and I'm not allowed to tinker with the Clearcase installation. The next time I encounter this issue (and that will certainly be soon), I'll check in from the reserved view and come back here if I get the predecessor is not latest error when checking in from the other views. Cheers.

Comment: Dynamic is easier: just check in

Comment: You may also want to review the development process you're using. If you have a workgroup that uses unreserved checkouts to edit the same files, you may want to discuss branching or using UCM. You could also use a trigger script to block unreserved checkouts.

Comment: Indeed, staying on the same branch for so long was a poor design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "make it impossible for me to check the file in from the other views afterward.":

It will still be possible, but the checkin will merge your checked out version with the last version.

If you are using a snapshot view, update it first (as seen in ""[Unable to check in file" error when checking in a RobotJ script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21133455)")

Comment: Alright that works pretty well. But it seems that when checking in with the no comment option, no merging is offered. That was a bit confusing to me.